# Adding a sorted tuple to a dictionary as a key

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, defaultdict

I am very new to Python and i am trying my best to learn Python. I have been trying to implement a community detection algorithm that i came across and i would really appreciate if i could get help from anyone here.

I have a **defaultdict(list)**, my input, which looks like :

```
input = [('B', ['D']), ('D', ['E']), ('F', ['E']), ('G', ['D', 'F'])]
```

Here, **'B', 'D', 'E'** etc represent nodes in a tree. The **key** in the dictionary represents **children** nodes and the **value** represents **parent** nodes. So in the above input, 'B' is a child of 'D', 'D' is a child of 'E' etc.

I am trying to create a dictionary with **tuples**(in sorted order) as **keys** and **int** as **values**. The expected output is:

```
output = [(('A', 'B'), 1.0), (('B', 'C'), 1.0), (('B', 'D'), 3.0), (('D', 'E'), 4.5), (('D', 'G'), 0.5), (('E', 'F'), 1.5), (('F', 'G'), 0.5)]
```

In the above output, the key is a tuple which represents an edge in the input. For ex : ('A' , 'B') represents an edge between A and B and the int value is something that i calculate.

I would love to know know how this can be done.

I have tried the following:

1)

```
edges = []
for node,parents in input.items():
    for p in sorted(parents):
        tup = (node,p)
        tup = sorted(tup)
        edges.append(tup)
/*output of the above line: [['E', 'F'], ['D', 'E'], ['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C'], ['B', 'D'], ['D', 'G'], ['F', 'G']]*/
```

And then i thought i will pull values from this list to a dict.  Obviously, i got a dict with **key** of type **List** and further the items in list were not sorted.

2)

```
edges = {}

for node,parents in node2parents.items():
    for p in sorted(parents):
        t = (node,p)
        t = sorted(t)
        edges[t] = 0
```

On executing the above, i got a **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

I have tried few other ways, but none proved to be successful. It would be great if someone could help me learn how i could do this.

PS : I would have posted evidences of more "failed" efforts of mine, but i dint want to waste your time by making you go through all the stupid ways i have been trying to accomplish my goals. Also, i googled and tried if i could find an answer to my question. Though there were countless possible solutions, i still failed to implement the logic successfully. I am honestly trying to learn Python and it would be great if you could push me in the right direction.

Comment: `sorted` always returns a list, even if you pass it a tuple.

Comment: Note: none of the literals you've shown are dictionaries, they are all lists.

Comment: Yes!!My bad!!The way i have framed the question is misleading. Apologies for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`sorted` returns a new sorted `list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), regardless of the input's type. If you want the result to be a sorted `tuple`, just wrap the `sorted` call in the `tuple` constructor:

```
t = tuple(sorted(t))
```

For Python built-in types, only immutable types (e.g. `int`, `str`, or `tuple`s and `frozenset`s containing only other immutable types) are suitable for use as keys in `dict`s and values in `set`/`frozenset`s, which is why preserving the `tuple` type is important; `list` is mutable, and to avoid a sticky situation where a mutable object like a `list` is added to a `dict`, then changed (so suddenly the hash and equality comparisons for it don't correspond to where it was bucketed), rendering it unfindable and violating the `dict` assumptions, they prohibit using mutable built-in types completely.

Comment: wow!!Worked like a charm!!I tried it and i got the output as expected. Made the changes you asked me to. Thank you so much.

Comment: Brilliant explanation!!